# Can I use <stdatomic.h> from C11 in Linux driver, or do I must to use Linux functions of memory-barriers?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

Can I use [`#include <stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) and [`atomic_thread_fence()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) with [`memory_order`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) from C11 in Linux driver (kernel-space), or do I must to use Linux functions of memory-barriers:

- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt
- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt

Using:

- Linux-kernel 2.6.18 or greater
- GCC 4.7.2 or greater

Comment: You don't want to link to cppreference, C11 is still young and people don't know it has `stdatomic.h`. FYI it is specified in 7.17.

Comment: @cnicutar  In my question: include, function and enum are clickable, or what do you mean about 7.17?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are writing kernel code, you should do it in C, and do it in the version of C required by the current kernel (shipping gcc). If you want to get it accepted into mainline (or write it as if it were going to get accepted), you should use the Linux functions. You will also find that they work without unexpected surprises, and you will get better debugging help.

Summary: use the linux functions.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that, because drivers can not be crossplatform across different OS, then does not make sense to use crossplatform atomic functions, and better to use platform specific functions?

Comment: Drivers could theoretically share cross platform elements, however they would normally abstract OS / kernel primitives to do thinks like mutexes and atomic accesses; however, drivers written like that would be unlikely to be accepted into the kernel. What I'm saying is you should write your driver as if it should be accepted into mainline (least surprise, more debugging support from the community), and that means using the kernel's own stuff for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
It seems not to work.
With or without  does not make any difference.
Driver may compile but the lib will fallback to plain integers or NOP

---

It seems to work.

`atomic_store()` and `atomic_load()` provide the threads synchronization I need between the kernel module driver and the userland program. 
What is not sure is that if a fallback method is employed, I mean, usage of standard integer and regular assembly instructions by the compiler.

Feel free to give a look in [source codes](http://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq)
 in functions: 
`intelfreq.c / Core_Cycle()`
and
`corefreqd.c / Core_Cycle()`